# How to pass a variable to the define macro used for accessing the path in system verilog

Tags: macros, system-verilog, define-syntax

I am using a define macro to set the path for a module,
ie, 
`define DUT_PATH(CH) dut_top.u_channel_```CH``_mode

and using this define macro in a module where we are passing the channel number ,

module channel_oper # (int channel_num = 0)
(
input logic addr_base;
) ;

assign addr_base = `DUT_PATH(channel_num).addr_base ;

endmodule

In the top file , we are calling the module as

channel_oper(3);  //channel_oper(channel_num)

where I expect the output of the addr_base to be  **dut_top.u_channel_3_mode.addr_base** , but I am getting the value assigned as dut_top.u_channel_**channel_num**_mode.addr_base and cross dereferenece error .

Can you please provide me a solution or any suggestions for this to use a parameterised vaiable to the define macro.

In this case, genvar or generate block could not be used as this is not used for any manipulation . This is used to access the different path for the different channel number and we are passing the channel number from the top module . The module channel operation takes the channel number from the parameter and goes to that particular channel path and takes the vaiable.

Comment: You cannot do this. Possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable value to a macro in SystemVerilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007162/how-to-pass-a-variable-value-to-a-macro-in-systemverilog)

Comment: no in this case , it is used to access the different path location where genvar and generate could not be used . So I need to know how to access the different path using define in a module .

Comment: You need to understand why you are getting the results you see and not getting what you expect. The other post explains that very well. Your solution is also complicated by the fact that you have a number embedded in a path name which might as well be any arbitrary character.

Comment: all macros are just a text-level substitution which is happening before the code is parsed and analyzed. so, you cannot use compile-time elements (param values) in pre-processing step. So, you cannot do it in verilog.  In test bench you can probably find a way to manipulate strings, most likely using a back-door mechanism,  i.e. dpis or vpi.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which could work in some cases (works in synopsys vcs/system verilog). It generates an instance name per channel but in a bit different form. It automatically inserts [num] from the loop iteration and also inserts an additional hierarchy for the 'if' statement, i named it as 'number'. You also would need to know the max number of channels to organize your loop correctly.

```
module top;
   mod#(1) mod1();
   mod#(4) mod2();
endmodule // top

module mod#(int P = 0);
   for (genvar i = 0; i < 10; i++) begin: channel
      if (i == P) begin:number
        mx mx();
      end
   end
endmodule

module mx;
   initial
     $display("%m");
   initial #2 $finish;
endmodule // mx
```

Now, here are the lists of the 'mx' instances:

```
top.mod1.channel[1].number.mx
top.mod2.channel[4].number.mx
```