# Instantiate vector of custom modules in Verilog with additional parameters

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I have a custom module in Verilog that takes several inputs and a few parameters.

```
module modA ( 
    input inp1, input inp2, ... output out);
    parameter my_addr;
...
endmodule
```

For various reasons associated with the specific hardware that I'm using, I need to create many instances of this module, each time with a different parameter (because my_addr corresponds to a specific location in memory that I am then accessing from the host). Moreover, I would like an easy way to access all of the outputs. I thought of doing something like

```
wire [9:0] outputs;
modA #(.my_addr) all_modA[9:0](.inp1(inp1), .inp2(inp2), .out(outputs));
```

So then I would have a vector of elements of all_modA, and the nth element of outputs would correspond to the nth instantiation of modA. That sounds like it would work well, except I need to pass a unique address to each instantiation. When I was just doing one instantiation at a time, it was quite easy to just define a parameter, but I don't see how I could pass a unique identifier each time.

Is there any way to accomplish this? The problem is, if I use a for loop, then I don't see how I can instantiate each modA with a unique identifier. If I don't use a for loop, then I'm not sure how to add a unique identifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `generate` block over here. **Generate blocks are evaluated during elaboration of the design**. They do not execute at simulation time and the result is determined before the simulation begins. Therefore, **all expressions in generate schemes shall be constant expressions**, deterministic at elaboration time.

Give different values to `my_addr` according to the requirement. Also, you can **apply some label identifier** to `begin-end` block. This as an *optional feature* for generate blocks, but **very highly recommended**. By doing so, **a unique hierarchical path** can be seen to every instance of `modA` is different for each module.

For your code, I have created a testbench that instantiates the module with changing value of `my_addr` and `outputs` bus driving the `out` signal.

```
module modA #(parameter int my_addr) (input inp1, input inp2,output out);

  initial $display("%m: %d",my_addr);
endmodule

module top();
wire [9:0] outputs;
  genvar i; // generate iterator
  generate
    for(i=0;i<9;i++) begin: some_identifier
      // my_addr = i+1 for every module
      modA #(.my_addr(i+1)) all_modA(.inp1(inp1), .inp2(inp2), .out(outputs[i])); // Multiple modules
      end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

For more information, refer to [IEEE 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) Section 27. Similar questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36231922/can-i-use-generate-endgenerate-block-inside-initial-in-systemverilog) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443658/systemverilog-passing-parameters-from-an-interface-that-instantiates-another).

Comment: How would I determine what some_identifier is?

Comment: It is **any** identifier of the `begin..end` block. This is a user-defined label of generate block. One can use any string over here.

Comment: In my particular case, each output is a 16 bit wire. Would I then write      
    "wire [15:0] outputs [0:10];"?

Comment: This will create a bus of 11 wires, each of width 16.